# After 3rd call the function works perfectly [ Google Charts]

Tags: javascript

I have created a Google chart and the first time I call the function i get this error:

> Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined
>
> drawChart callDraw onclick

the second time i call it i says:

> Uncaught Error: Not an array
>   in this line:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(inputData);
```

Head:

```
var array1 = [[80,100,120,130,140,120,105,60],[70,90,100,115,130,120,102,65]];
var array2 = [[12,14,16,17,18,17,16,9],[10,13,14,17,17,16,14,11]];
var size = 8;
var size2 = 2;


function callDraw(array1,array2,size,size2){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
    var i=0,j=0;
    var both ={};

    for(i= 0; i < size2 ; i++)
      for(j=0; j < size; j++)
        both[array1[i][j]] = array2[i][j];

    var count=0;
    for(var key in both)
      count ++;

    var inputData = [];
    for(i=0;i<count+1;i++)
      inputData[i]=[]; 
    inputData[0][0] = "Number of staff";
    inputData[0][1] = "Number of traffic";

    var counter=1;
    for(var key in both){
        inputData[counter][0] = key;
        inputData[counter][1] = both[key];
        counter++
        console.log(key + " " + both[key]);
    }  
    drawChart();

  function drawChart() {

    console.log("I am here");
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(inputData);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'No. of traffic',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {title: 'No. of staff' ,minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    inputData = [];
  }
}
 </script>
```

Body:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<p id="test"></p>
<button onclick="callDraw(array1,array2,size,size2)">Click me</button>
```

If I deleted the draChart() call from callDraw the first error disappears  and it only works one time. I need to be able to call the function multiple time because later i will change the input not to be a static array of arrays but something dinamic.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This error occurs when google visualization is not loaded yet. So you have to wait until it loads, for that, you have to change this line of your code: `drawChart();` to this: `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

Comment: Thank you so much :D , i earlier tried putting that on the begining of the code but it didn't work, now it works.
If you want you can answer and I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: OK, Thanks. also I'm not sure, why are you passing your variables as parameter to your function. because you are creating these variables _array1, array2, size, size2_ in `global scope`. So you already have access to them in the function without the need to pass them by parameter.

Comment: I am passing them because this is a shorter version of the code. In the longer version you are getting them from a table. It says to write only the important part when asking a question :D

Comment: OK, in that case I will update my answer and put the parameters back in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as I mentioned in my comment, the problem is that you have to wait until google visualization is loaded and then draw your chart. so you have to use `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback()` callback.

Also when you have arrays, you can use something like this `array1.length` to get the array length. so you do not need to set a fixed value for  the variable as the array length.

So with all these changes, your code would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<p id="test"></p>
<button onclick="javascript:callDraw(array1,array2,size,size2);">Click me</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var array1 = [[80,100,120,130,140,120,105,60],[70,90,100,115,130,120,102,65]];
var array2 = [[12,14,16,17,18,17,16,9],[10,13,14,17,17,16,14,11]];
var size = array1[0].length;
var size2 = array1.length;

function callDraw(array1,array2,size,size2){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    var i=0,j=0;
    var both ={};

    for(i= 0; i < size2 ; i++)
        for(j=0; j < size; j++)
            both[array1[i][j]] = array2[i][j];

    var count=0;
    for(var key in both)
        count ++;

    var inputData = [];
    for(i=0;i<count+1;i++)
        inputData[i]=[]; 

    inputData[0][0] = "Number of staff";
    inputData[0][1] = "Number of traffic";

    var counter=1;
    for(var key in both){
        inputData[counter][0] = key;
        inputData[counter][1] = both[key];
        counter++
        console.log(key + " " + both[key]);
    }  
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        console.log("I am here");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(inputData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            hAxis: {title: 'No. of traffic',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
            vAxis: {title: 'No. of staff' ,minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        inputData = [];
    }
}
```